# Hyperref after subappendix

Tags: hyperref, appendix

I have a book documentclass for which I would like to include subappendices after each chapter. Something seems to go wrong with the autoref names after including a subappendix.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
Reference to \autoref{chapter_2}. Reference to \autoref{appendix_1}. Reference to \autoref{chapter_3}.

\chapter{Two}
\label{chapter_2}

\begin{subappendices}
\section{hello}
\label{appendix_1}
\end{subappendices}

\chapter{Three}
\label{chapter_3}

\end{document}
```

Of which the output for chapter One is:

[image]

The reference to chapter_2 is as expected. Two problems with the output:

1. I would like

> Reference to section 2.A.

to be:

> Reference to Appendix 2.A.

(or similar; but an "appendix" somewhere in the autoref). How can I achieve that?

2. The reference to chapter_3 is

> Appendix 3

even though I would expect/want this to be:

> chapter 3

Why is that chapter referenced as an appendix?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: well regarding chapter 3 I would say the appendix package is doing nonsense here. And regarding the section, that autoref is not powerful enough for this (it tries to guess the name from the counter and this doesn't change here.

Comment: I changed your section 3 to chapter 3.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is right that the _appendix_ package “is doing nonsense” here: _hyperref.sty_ defines `\def\Hy@chapapp{\Hy@chapterstring}`. This is overwritten by `\xdef\Hy@chapapp{\Hy@appendixstring}` in _appendix.sty_. Hence, adding `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Hy@chapapp}{\Hy@chapterstring}
\makeatother` after `\end{subappendices}` to restore the original meaning of `\Hy@chapapp` solves the second issue.

Comment: Alternatively, use
```\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@resets@pp{\xdef}{\def}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\@resets@ppsub{\xdef}{\def}{}{\fail}
\makeatother```
after loading the _appendix_ package, as Ulrike Fischer suggested on GitHub: https://github.com/wspr/herries-press/issues/34#issuecomment-935770824.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\cref` from `cleveref` immediately fixed the second problem.
Using `\label[appendix]{appendix_1}` fixed the first problem.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
Reference to \autoref{chapter_2}. Reference to \autoref{appendix_1}. Reference to \autoref{chapter_3}.

Reference to \cref{chapter_2}. Reference to \Cref{appendix_1}. Reference to \cref{chapter_3}.


\chapter{Two}
\label{chapter_2}

\begin{subappendices}
\section{hello}
\label[appendix]{appendix_1}
\end{subappendices}

\chapter{Three}
\label{chapter_3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll accept this answer because using cleveref solved both problems for me. The second as you indicated and the first by overriding the cross-reference type of the label in the appendix by `\label[appendix]{appendix_1}`.

Comment: @MMM, Good to know that both problems are solved!!

Comment: I just updated my answer to include your solution for the first problem.